# Server restart results in never ending Bad_ServiceUnsupported errors, onSubscriptionTransferFailed not called

Tags: opc-ua, opc, milo

my Milo client (sdk 0.4.1) subscribes on server events by use of UaSubscription and can receive events sucessfully. But once I restart the server, the clients only logs errors in an endless loop in the form of:

> [ERROR] 2021-06-11 17:29:11.467 [milo-netty-event-loop-0]
> UascClientMessageHandler -
> errorMessage=ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_ServiceUnsupported,
> value=0x800B0000, quality=bad}, reason=null}

Unfortunately implementing the onSubscriptionTransferFailed method does not help because it is never called.

```
    client.getSubscriptionManager().addSubscriptionListener(new UaSubscriptionManager.SubscriptionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscriptionTransferFailed(UaSubscription subscription, StatusCode statusCode) {
                        try {
                            LOGGER.info("onSubscriptionTransferFailed");
                            client.getSubscriptionManager().clearSubscriptions();
                            client.disconnect().get();
                            run(client, serverAddress, biConsumer, requestedPublishingInterval);
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                            LOGGER.error("Failed re-subscription: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }
   }
```

Any idea how I can get the client to detect its current problem and resubscribe on server events?

Thank you in advance.

**Update**:
Found this commit https://github.com/eclipse/milo/commit/e854374845e6c5f46a7b033c2c62cee2ee10622a and was able to fix the problem by just increasing the Milo client sdk version to 0.6.1. Version 0.5.3 should probably also fix it but I did not test it.

Comment: I was going to suggest upgrading for exactly that fix. If it’s still not working then it might be useful to take a Wireshark capture of what is happening as the client reconnects. If you have control over logger levels in your application then setting the SessionFsm logger to DEBUG or TRACE helps as well.

Comment: That said, you should not be disconnecting the client in the onSubscriptionTransferFailed callback. That is just going to result in a disconnected client with no subscriptions. Let it reconnect on its own. It’s also going to screw things up because it will be called once for each subscription that fails to transfer.